# Improving Twitter's typeahead.js performance with remote data using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, typeahead.js

I have a database with roughly 1.2M names. I'm using Twitter's typeahead.js to remotely fetch  the autocomplete suggestions when you type someone's name. In my local environment this takes roughly 1-2 seconds for the results to appear after you stop typing (the autocomplete doesn't appear while you are typing), and 2-5+ seconds on the deployed app on Heroku (using only 1 dyno).

I'm wondering if the reason why it only shows the suggestions after you stop typing (and a few seconds delay) is because my code isn't as optimized?

The script on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navPersonSearch").typeahead({
    name: 'people',
    remote: 'name_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
  })
    .keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("form").trigger('submit');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The keydown snippet is because without it my form doesn't submit for some reason when pushing enter.

my django view:

```
def name_autocomplete(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q','')
    if(len(query) > 0):
        results = Person.objects.filter(short__istartswith=query)
        result_list = []
        for item in results:
            result_list.append(item.short)
    else:
        result_list = []

    response_text = json.dumps(result_list, separators=(',',':'))
    return HttpResponse(response_text, content_type="application/json")
```

The short field in my Person model is also indexed. Is there a way to improve the performance of my typeahead?

Comment: Can you use your browser's analytics (Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug) to see a) when your requests are being made and b) how long they're taking?

Comment: Yes...like I said the local version of my typeahead requests takes roughly 1-2 seconds. On Heroku it takes at the minimum of 2 seconds and can be up to 8-9 seconds. The longer requests have a very long "waiting" period compared to the shorter ones.

Comment: is this code working for you?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is directly related Django, but I may be wrong. I can offer some generic advice for this kind of situations:

(My money is on #4 or #5 below).

1) What is an average "ping" from your machine to Heroku? If it's far, that's a little bit extra overhead. Not much, though. Certainly not much when compared to then 8-9 seconds you are referring to. The penalty will be larger with `https`, mind you.

2) Check the value of `waitLimitFn` and `rateLimitWait` in your `remote` dataset. Are they the default?

3) In all likelyhood, the problem is database/dataset related. First thing to check is how long it takes you to establish a connection to the database (do you use a connection pool?).

4) Second thing: how long it takes to run the query. My bet is on this point or the next. Add debug prints, or use NewRelic (even the free plan is OK). Have a look at the generated query and make sure it is indexed. Have your DB "explain" the execution plan for such a query and make it is uses the index.

5) Third thing: are the results large? If, for example, you specify "J" as the query, I imagine there will be lots of answers. Just getting them and streaming them to the client will take time. In such cases:

5.1) Specify a `minLength` for your dataset. Make it at least 3, if not 4.

5.2) Limit the result set that your DB query returns. Make it return no more than 10, say.

6) I am no Django expert, but make sure the way you use your model in Django doesn't make it load the entire table into memory first. Just sayin'.

HTH.

Comment: For your points 1-2, the pings and values are normal. 3. I'm using heroku so that handles the connection to the db. 4. I'm unfamiliar with testing that stuff, so I'll look into it. 5. Yes, I've recently limited the size of input and its returns and it's still pretty slow. Thank you for your points, I'll keep trying to work on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
        results = Person.objects.filter(short__istartswith=query)
        result_list = []
        for item in results:
            result_list.append(item.short)
```

Probably not the only cause of your slowness but this horrible from a performance point of view: never loop over a django queryset. To assemble a list from a django queryset you should always use values_list. In this specific case:

```
        results = Person.objects.filter(short__istartswith=query)
        result_list = results.values_list('short', flat=True)
```

This way you are getting the single field you need straight from the db instead of: getting all the table row, creating a Person instance from it and finally reading the single attribute from it.

Answer (score 0):

Nitzan covered a lot of the main points that would improve performance, but unlike him I think this might be directly related to Django (at at least, sever side).

A quick way to test this would be to update your `name_autocomplete` method to simply return 10 random generated strings in the format that Typeahead expects. (The reason we want them random is so that Typeahead's caching doesn't skew any results).

What I suspect you will see is that Typeahead is now running pretty quick and you should start seeing results appear as soon as your `minLength` of string has been typed.

If that is the case then we will need to into what could be slowing the query up, my Python skills are non-existent so I can't help you there sorry!

If that isn't the case then I would maybe consider doing some logging of when `$('#navPersonSearch')` calls `typeahead:initialized` and `typeahead:opened` to see if they bring up anything odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and your server side code would be roughly like:

```
def autocomplete(request):
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:5]  # or how many names you need
suggestions = [result.first_name for result in sqs]
# you have to configure typeahead how to process returned data, this is a simple example
data = json.dumps({'q': suggestions})  
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Debugging a similar issue, I found a bug. On line 3, it should be: suggestions = [result.object.first_name for result in sqs]